# Typescript does not enforce typing when returning a generic from an abstract function

Tags: generics, typescript, abstract

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Typescript 2.0.3.0.

I have a pretty simple inheritance model where my base class has an abstract method that returns a Promise.

As you can see, the base class uses generics to restrict the type of model that subclasses are using, in this case, TModel.

When I declare an abstract method, GetVehicle, that returns TModel, Typescript will force my sub-class (GrandPrix) to return type "Car" - this is great.

However, if I change the return type to Promise, Typescript will no longer enforce the return type:

```
interface IVehicle {
    Name:string;
}

class Car implements IVehicle {
    Name: "CAR";
}

class MotorBike implements IVehicle {
    Name: "MotorBike";
}


abstract class Race<TModel extends IVehicle> {

    protected abstract GetVehiclePromise(): Promise<TModel>;
    protected abstract GetVehicle(): TModel;
}

class GrandPix extends Race<Car> {
    // This works - it has to be type 'Car'
    protected GetVehicle(): Car { return null; }

    // This works, but SHOULD NOT - I can return Promise<anything_at_all> and it still compiles. Even something non-IVehicle like Promise<string>
    protected GetVehiclePromise(): Promise<MotorBike> { return null; }
}
```

Of interest, I have also tried replacing the use of Promise with another class that accepts a generic - same problem:

```
class Simple<T> {
    ID: "";
}

abstract class Race<TModel extends IVehicle> {
    protected abstract GetVehiclePromise(): Simple<TModel>;
}

class GrandPix extends Race<Car> {
    // Also compiles when it should not
    protected GetVehiclePromise(): Simple<MotorBike> { return null; }
}
```

So this is not an issue with the Promise<> declaration, it is to do with generics (I think).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example will fail as expected in Typescript 2.2 (probably 2.1 as well), I believe this was due to this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9953) with Promises in Typescript.

The second example compiles because of how TypeScript handles type compatibility with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#generics), in particular `Simple<T>` does not use the type argument.

If you make the following change you will get the expected error:

```
class Simple<T> {
    ID: T;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right!  The upgrade helped with the first issue.  And thankyou for clarification on the second.  A true red-herring, I dismissed a potential issue with promises once I saw the second issue manifest.